# ノード数が多くなると処理が重くなる

Tags: swift, spritekit

いつもお世話になっております。

SKSpriteNodeを利用したノードを50個以上生成すると、
フレーム数が落ちたり、view.showsFPSが表示されなかったりします。
（iPhone 4Sを利用してます）

解決策として、画面外のSKSpriteNodeを削除したりすることが一般的ですが、
他に、画像を小さくすると処理を軽くすることもできました。

他に処理を軽くする改善策があったりしますでしょうか。

ノードは、SKSpriteNodeの他に、SKShapeNode、SKLabelNodeも利用しております。
どのノードも利用するとそれぞれ１ノードとしてカウントされ、（view.showsFPS）
ノード数が多くなると重くなることを認識しました。
50ノードで表現しているゲームレイアウトを10ノードにしたりする技能があったりしますでしょうか。

コードの質問ではなく申し訳ございません。

回答頂けると幸いです。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 技術要件が明示されているので、ご質問としては問題ないと思う(spritekitはタグに入れた方が良かったでしょう)のですが、iOSのサポート対象デバイスからはずれてかなりになるiPhone 4Sをサポートする必要がおありなのでしょうか? [参考](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/jp/)

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。当方の手持ちの端末がiPhone 4Sで、壊れることもなく使えてますので、検証機として何かアプリを作ってみようと思った次第です。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。当方SpriteKitに関しては単なるホビイストで、お役に立てそうな知識も持ち合わせないのですが、「なぜかな？」と疑問に思われる点は明らかにしいていただいた方が、回答者が回答しやすいかと思ったもので。サポート対象機種の中でもローエンドとハイエンドとはかなりの能力差があるので、どっちみちローエンド機種対策は要りますから、余計なお世話だったかもしれません。失礼いたしました。